# Common interface for derived classes using SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

I want to add (dynamic) properties to a C++ class, which can be of several types (e.g. `float`, `int`, `bool`). Depending on their value type, different controls should be shown in the interface.

To do this, I created a simple Property class using SFINAE for the `type()` function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
class Property
{
public:
  enum Type {
    Undefined = -1,
    Int,
    Float,
    Bool,
  };

  explicit Property(const std::string& name) : name_(name) { }

  const std::string& name() const { return name_; }

  // specialization for floating point type() getter
  template<class U = T,
           typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<U>::value>::type* = nullptr>
  Type type() const {
    return Type::Float;
  }

  // specialization for integer type() getter
  template<class U = T,
           typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<U>::value>::type* = nullptr>
  Type type() const {
    return Type::Int;
  }

  // specialization for boolean type() getter
  template<class U = T,
           typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, bool>::value>::type* = nullptr>
  Type type() const {
    return Type::Bool;
  }

private:
  std::string name_;
  T value_;
};

int main() {
  // this works
  auto fProp = new Property<float>("float property");
  std::cout << fProp->type() << std::endl;
}
```

So far, this works reasonably well. Now, the problems comes when I want to store several of these properties in a vector. For this, I created a common interface, and changed the class accordingly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

class IProperty
{
  // common interface for all typed Property<T>'s
public:
  enum Type {
    Undefined = -1,
    Int,
    Float,
    Bool,
  };

  virtual const std::string& name() const = 0;
};

template <class T>
class Property : public IProperty
{
public:
  explicit Property(const std::string& name) : name_(name) { }

  const std::string& name() const { return name_; }

  // specialization for floating point type() getter
  template<class U = T,
           typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<U>::value>::type* = nullptr>
  Type type() const {
    return Type::Float;
  }

  // specialization for integer type() getter
  template<class U = T,
           typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<U>::value>::type* = nullptr>
  Type type() const {
    return Type::Int;
  }

  // specialization for boolean type() getter
  template<class U = T,
           typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, bool>::value>::type* = nullptr>
  Type type() const {
    return Type::Bool;
  }

private:
  std::string name_;
  T value_;
};

int main() {

  // works
  auto fProp = new Property<float>("float property");
  std::cout << fProp->type() << std::endl;

  std::vector<IProperty*> properties;
  properties.push_back(fProp);

  // error: 'class IProperty' has no member named 'type'
  for (auto iprop : properties) {
    std::cout << iprop->type() << std::endl;  
  }

}
```

As you see, I can't call the `type()` method because it's not defined for the `IProperty` class. I tried defining a pure virtual `IProperty::type()`, but of course this doesn't work with the templated derived class.

What are my options here?

Comment: Isn't std::is_integral<U> and std::is_same<U, bool> ambitious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to extend your current solution would be indeed to add a pure virtual function in the base class.  To make it compile, add an additional virtual function in the derived class that can even have the same name as the templated variants (it might be confusing, though):

```
class IProperty
{
    // ...
    virtual Type type() const = 0;
};

template <class T>
class Property : public IProperty
{
public:
    // ...

    // here type() is not a template, so it can be virtual
    virtual Type type() const override
    {
        return type<T>();
    }
};
```

Now, if you use something like

```
auto fProp = new Property<float>("float property");
std::cout << fProp->type() << std::endl;
```

it will actually call the new interface function instead of the templated function.

To call the template directly, you have to explicitly say so:

```
auto fProp = new Property<float>("float property");
// note the <>
std::cout << fProp->type<>() << std::endl;
```

You might actually want to declare your internal (templated) type() functions as private, since they are not part of the interface (IPorperty) and should not be exposed. This would prohibit calling `fProp->type<>()`.

Comment: I like this solution, thank you! Just one question, could you briefly explain why this works? Why is it possible to have ``virtual IProperty::type()`` as well as ``virtual Property::type()`` and ``IProperty<T>::type()``?

Comment: The template parameter is part of the function signature. Therefore, the function signatures of the templated version and the non-templated version of type() are different. IProperty::type() only refers to Property::type() (the polymorphic usage).

Answer (score 2):

Specialization:

```
class IProperty
{
  // common interface for all typed Property<T>'s
public:
  enum Type {
    Undefined = -1,
    Int,
    Float,
    Bool,
  };

  virtual const std::string& name() const = 0;
  virtual Type type() const { return Type::Undefined }
};

template <class T>
class Property : public IProperty
{
public:
  explicit Property(const std::string& name) : name_(name) { }

  const std::string& name() const override { return name_; }

  Type type() const override;

private:
  std::string name_;
  T value_;
};

template <> Type Property<float>::type() const { return Type::Float;}
template <> Type Property<int>::type() const { return Type::Int;}
template <> Type Property<bool>::type() const { return Type::Bool;}
```

Comment: you dont respect the using of is_xxxx<T>, allowing any type in input

Comment: Since there exists no specialization for other types, the linking stage fails for things like `Property<double>`.
Depending on the design, this might actually be desired. However, the solution without SFINAE does not behave exactly as the author's solution. It is acutally more restrictive.

Answer (score 1):

```
class IProperty 
{ 
public:
  virtual Type getType() const=0; 
  enum {...}
};

template < class T > class PropertyByType : public IProperty
{
  // implement here the differents type() method 

  // then :
  virtual Type getType(){ return type<T>();}
}

template < class T >
class Property : public PropertyByType<T>
{
  // ...
}
```

Now a `Property<T>*` is castable into `IProperty*`, and so have access to `getType` method